# How much data we can get from client's ip in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ip-address

I want to know which type of data and how much data we can obtained from client's IP. For example his location, city etc or any other information.

Comment: If you do manage to derive information from the IP I would hope in the majority of cases it will be right most of the time (Other with more experience will know better than me), obvisouly with most smart phones having GPS these days that's what will be used there but as for non-mobile applications, i'm not 100%.

Answer (score 2):

You can't depend on any info derived from an IP - even if it's a static IP, it could be someone sitting in a library!

Comment: I believe behind proxies and things like that will change resulting information as well. Suggestion from: [ASP Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/892765.aspx) 
To get the IP address of the machine and not the proxy use the following code

HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

Comment: And with mobiles it's no better: http://hello.handsetdetection.com/entries/180214-mobile-ip-address-to-geo-mapping

Answer (score 1):

With the IP Address you should be able to use one of the many Geo Location services (in form of a library, a web service or a simple programatic http request to whois.sc) to find out city, country, Internet Service Provider, etc. As far as I know, none of these libraries or web services are 100% accurate.